# Extending a class defined in a gem

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Let's say I have a hypothetical gem, `my_gem`, that defines the class `AwesomeClass`, and the gem includes a binary that will *only* work on `AwesomeClass`, but *will* load any code in my `lib/` directory, say. I want to cleanly extend some of the class' methods, sometimes calling the equivalent of `super`.

Let's say it looks like this:

```
    class AwesomeClass
      def cool_method
       ...
      end
    end
```

And over here, in my library code, I want to do something like:

```
    AwesomeClass.class_eval
      def cool_method
       (call the original method here)
       ...
      end
    end
```

How would you do that? Is `alias` my only real option? Is there some nicer way I'm missing? Something other than `class_eval`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is alias my only real option?

Yes, if you want to open and directly modify a class. However, the better option is *not* opening 3rd party classes and monkey-patching them. You should either use inheritance, or composition: Build your own class which wraps an instance of `AwesomeClass`, provides its own `cool_method` that invokes the `AwesomeClass` method plus whatever additional functionality you need.

Comment: How would you see that working if the gem only ever wants an `AwesomeClass`, and not my own?

Comment: @DanielBogan Then the Gem is built incorrectly, that isn't how Ruby's type system is meant to work. As long as your object supports the same method calls as an `AwesomeClass`, the gem shouldn't be able to reject it.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Okay, rad, thank you!